# Django- update() and get_or_create() check entry count before uploading/updating

Tags: python, django, csv

Is there any way to check how many objects would be updated or created before committing to the DB? Something like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Upload File? {{created_objects}} Objects will be created. {{updated_objects}} Objects will be updated')">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And then in the view

```
with open(str(csv_file)) as file:
    number_of_lines = len(file.readlines())
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        id += 1
        try:
            _, p = CSV3.objects.get_or_create(id = id, defaults = {'gebaeudebereich' : row[0],
                                                       'gebaeudenummer' : row[1], 'ebene' : row[2],
                                                       'raum' : row[3], 'dose' : row[4], 'switch_ip' : row[5],
                                                       'switch_port' : row[6], 'datum' : row[7], 'akteur' : row[8]})
            created_objects += 1
        except IntegrityError:
            _, p = CSV3.objects.filter(id = id).update(gebaeudebereich=row[0], gebaeudenummer=row[1], ebene=row[2], raum=row[3],
                                                      dose=row[4], switch_ip=row[5], switch_port = row[6], datum = row[7], akteur = row[8])
            updated_objects += 1
            #messages.INFO("Objects Created: %(created_objects)s")
            #messages.INFO("Objects Updated: %(updated_objects)s")

   return redirect('appp:index')
form = UploadFileForm()
return render(
request, "appp/file_upload.html", {"form": form, 'created_objects' : created_objects, 'updated_objects' : updated_objects}
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think its possible. Maybe before the data is sent to Django, its possible to count using JS.

Comment: Yeah that is okey. Do you have a link or a hint that could be helpful because I haven't found anything because I think it is sort of a special problem.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.braingia.org/webnotes/2016/02/07/parsing-a-csv-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to pass the variables created_objects and updated_objects to the templated after they are counted up?

Comment: if mean, after you have submitted the form, then yes its possible

Comment: I updated my question to better show what i mean. But I would need to pass them before submitting right? Because the user should confirm the number of uploaded/updated objects. Is that also possible without reconstructing the whole code?

Comment: No, as @ruddra says, it's not possible the way you're trying to. You can do two things: 1. Do the check in javascript locally or 2. Let the user upload the file to a django view, save the file to disk and calculate the number of objects (without actually creating the objects) and return a confirmation page with another form that references the file, if the user confirms use the saved file to actually create the objects in the database in a second view. But this would query your db twice: once to calculate the values in the first view, and a second time to commit the changes to the db.

Comment: By the way since the only thing that matters is the number of rows (you just match row number with id without checking the content), why don't you just pass the total `CSV3.objects.count()` in the first view and then in javascript check how many rows are in the file? updated_objects = min(rows, CSV3.objects.count()) and created_objects = max(0, rows - updated_objects).

Comment: The number of rows only matters when it comes to the create(). When it comes to the update() information, the content does matter. I thought about subtracting the number of current rows in the database with `.count()` from the rows of the file that is about to be uploaded (number_of_lines in the question). And for update(), i thought about comparing the current database with the contents of the new file. But  the passing to the template does not work because it is not in the same scope.

Comment: The big problem is I have never worked with javascript so I don't even know what how to implement and include it in the templates.